# Probability in game shop items

Tags: probability, statistics

In a game I can visit a shop regularly to buy an upgrade for my characters. 
The shop offers three possible items.
These items are chosen from three different pools. Pool A, Pool B and Pool C.
If I buy one of the upgrades, another offering comes in its place and it is again randomly selected from one of the three pools.

Each time I visit the shop, there will always be a minimum of one offering from Pool C to start with.

I cannot buy anything from Pools A and B.

I only want items from Pool C and I have limitless supply of currency for this pool.

This means that each time when I buy an offering from Pool C, it gets replaced and if it comes from Pool C, I can buy it again.

What is the average number of offerings from Pool C i can expect for each visit to the shop if I buy every offering from this pool.

---

The same situation applies. Only this time I have measured that the actual amount of Pool C offerings is 5.92 in more than 1000 visits. Is there any obvious math behind this measured result?

Answer (score 1):

Your $5.92$ average looks too high for uniform randomness.

If a type of item started with something from pool C, then the expected number of items you could take of that type would be $1+\frac13+\frac19+\cdots=1.5$.

Since there are three slots, the expected number of pool C items you could buy at each visit would be $1.5$, $3$ or $4.5$, depending on how many types started from pool C. All of these are significantly less than $5.92$.

The combined expectation will be some weighted average of these and so less than $5.92$, though you have not described a mechanism for the starting positions beyond *"Each time I visit the shop, there will always be a minimum of one offering from Pool C to start with."*